# Handle different cases for two different OS for twitter implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I want to implement connect to twitter functionality for iOS 5 and iOS 6. What would be the best way to integrate solution for both way?

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: From version iOS 5 apple give us in build twitter framework. So i think here not need any chance to check iOS version because twitter framework will support both iOS 5 and iOS 6 generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the IOS version using:

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

For example check like this which IOS version it is and use according to your requirement:

```
 if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] isEqualToString:@"5.0"] || [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] isEqualToString:@"5.1"])
 {
    //twitter functionality for iOS 5 
 }
 else if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] isEqualToString:@"6.0"])
 {
    //twitter functionality for iOS 6
 }
```

Comment: What base SDK i need to set here?? If i will go with above solution then with base sdk as 6.0 it says the few iOS 5 twitter methods are deprecated.please suggest.

Comment: handle different methods for both sdk. A method will be called depending upon IOS version

Comment: If I am using deprecated methods, will there be any issue in getting approval from Apple?

Comment: yes it might get problem n getting approval from Apple. But why to use deprecated methods as i suggested call appropriate methods according to IOS version